# Multi-select if Checked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, checkbox

I am not able to add `Checkbox` in column header to multi-select(select all) Rows of `Datagridview`, I *google*  it but they are giving me to add `checkbox` in row not in column header.

So that I'll select all check box column header click.
Please look at the image belowfor example. it is the listview image that i got form internet But I'm using `Datagridview`.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this from internet but I can't remember where is the link and originally comes from c#.

```
Private checkboxHeader231 As CheckBox
Private Sub show_chkBox()
    Dim rect As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columnIndexOfCheckBox, -1, True)
    ' set checkbox header to center of header cell. +1 pixel to position 
    rect.Y = 3
    rect.X = rect.Location.X + 8 + (rect.Width / 4)
    checkboxHeader231 = New CheckBox()
    With checkboxHeader231
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End With

    checkboxHeader231.Name = "checkboxHeader1"
    checkboxHeader231.Size = New Size(18, 18)
    checkboxHeader231.Location = rect.Location
    AddHandler checkboxHeader231.CheckedChanged, AddressOf checkboxHeader231_CheckedChanged
    DataGridView1.Controls.Add(checkboxHeader231)
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxHeader231_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim headerBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Controls.Find("checkboxHeader1", True)(0), CheckBox)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        row.Cells(columnIndexOfCheckBox).Value = headerBox.Checked
    Next
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```
   Sub Form1Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        show_chkBox()
   End Sub
```

I hope it will helps

Comment: @spajce: Nice hack but there's one thing... The checkbox does not move when the user scrolls the DataGridView to display additional columns on the left or right.

Comment: yes, adding some more creative effort we can achieve that `:)`